# How to pipe content in Emacs' buffer to external program, and print the result?

Tags: bash, emacs, elisp

How to pipe the selected content in Emacs' buffer to external bash script and then print its output? The script can read data from pipe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `shell-command-on-region` which is bound to <kbd>M-|</kbd>

e.g.:
<kbd>M-|</kbd> `sort | uniq -c` <kbd>RET</kbd>

With a prefix argument, the region is *replaced* by the output of the shell command (which effectively adds all shell commands to Emacs' editing toolkit; very useful when you know how to do something outside of Emacs, but don't know an equivalent native function).

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-|</kbd> `sort | uniq -c` <kbd>RET</kbd>